# Returning a PDF from S3 in Flask

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, flask, boto3

I'm trying to return a PDF in the browser in a Flask application. I'm using AWS S3 to store the files and boto3 as the SDK to interact with S3. My code so far is:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
                aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_KEY)
file = s3.Object(settings.S3_BUCKET_NAME, 'test.pdf')).get()
response = make_response(file)
response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
return response
```

I'm able to successfully retrieve the object from S3 in `file` using boto3, however that is a dictionary of which I'm not sure how to return the PDF from that

Comment: Have you though of this implementation? It would have to download the file from s3 into your server every time someone requests the file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that boto3 doesn't have a `readLines()` method but they do have a `read()` method, so it worked by doing:

```
response = make_response(file['Body'].read())
response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
return response
```